# Erro no Mysql: json_set does not exist

Tags: php, json

Atualmente estou utilizando o Laravel para construir alguns projetos (pessoal); não tenho experiência no framework, mas apareceu um problema, aparentemente devido ao MYSQL.

Criei uma tabela chamada `tabelateste` e nessa tabela as seguintes colunas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para atualizar a coluna `params` usei o update conforme a DOC do Laravel

```
update(['params->filter' => $request->input('data')]);
```

Porém é retornado o erro

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION
>   database.json_set does not exist (SQL: update `tabelateste` set
>   `params` = json_set(`params`, '$."filter"', 1,2,3) where
>   `account` = 18)

Realizei a mesma `query` gerada pelo Laravel diretamente no prompt do Mysql e retornou o mesmo erro

> FUNCTION database.json_set does not exist

A versão do meu Mysql é a 5.7, versão minima requisitada pelo Laravel na Doc.

Answer (score 0):

Ao verificar a versão do Mysql (5.7) na source.list e a do mariaDB (10.1) percebi que os pacotes estavam diferentes (os pacotes do mariaDB referente ao Mysql5.7+ são a partir do 10.2).

Resolvi removendo o mariaDB atual (10.1) e instalando outro.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://mirror.ufscar.br/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stretch main'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Essas configurações mudam de acordo com a versão do SO, essas são para `Debian 9 stretch`

Fontes:

[Setting UP MariaDB repos](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=UFSCar&distro=Debian&distro_release=stretch--stretch&version=10.2)

[Dependency problems - leaving unconfigured](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249530/mariadb-dependency-problems-leaving-unconfigured?answertab=active#tab-top)